# Google Maps multi floor selector not showing up on custom map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code for a map of the Smithsonian air and space museum, and the map on Google has multi floors available and a selector that allows you to switch between them.

Is there a way to have this selector show up on my map? 
code:
edit: Older post doesn't solve my issue, has google updated v3 for this yet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyARP6gVN4t8LL9pD-KtM3DCJbxWY4KSUUY&sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
        ['Smithsonian National Air and Space Museum', 38.88815, -77.01985],
        ['Lockheed Martin IMAX Theater', 38.888342, -77.019492]    
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 18,      
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.88758,-77.01998),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),        
        map: map,
        icon:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+ (i + 1) +'|50C9F8|000000',
        shadow:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow'     
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to have markers set on multiple floors, and I would like to implement this into my existing code if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing floor picker in google maps api for javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187052/showing-floor-picker-in-google-maps-api-for-javascript)